# Magento 2: Adding Extra Parameters to Exception

Tags: exception, magento2.3.2, webapi

I need to return error codes instead of messages in the exception.

For example, what I am looking for is below

```
throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__("number is incorrect"),"Err123");
```

So that only `Err123` is will be returned as web API output instead of the message.

Is there a way to do this with existing Exception classes or a new exception class needs to be created?